# How to retrieve the data frame used in a GEE model fit?

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a longitudinal data frame with multiple rows per id.

```
    > data("dietox")
    > head(dietox, 5)
   Pig    Evit    Cu Litter Start   Weight      Feed Time
1 4601 Evit000 Cu000      1  26.5 26.50000        NA    1
2 4601 Evit000 Cu000      1  26.5 27.59999  5.200005    2
3 4601 Evit000 Cu000      1  26.5 36.50000 17.600000    3
4 4601 Evit000 Cu000      1  26.5 40.29999 28.500000    4
5 4601 Evit000 Cu000      1  26.5 49.09998 45.200001    5
```

I am trying to fit a GEE model to predict `Weight` for each row of the data frame.

```
    library(gee)
    library(dplyr)

    > model1 <- gee(Weight ~ Start + Feed, id=Pig, data=dietox, corstr="exchangeable")
    > model1

 GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
 gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

Model:
 Link:                      Identity 
 Variance to Mean Relation: Gaussian 
 Correlation Structure:     Exchangeable 

Call:
gee(formula = Weight ~ Start + Feed, id = Pig, data = dietox, 
    corstr = "exchangeable")

Number of observations :  789 

Maximum cluster size   :  11 


Coefficients:
(Intercept)       Start        Feed 
  5.1539561   0.9384232   0.4294209
```

I now want to be able to add a new column to the data frame- `prediction`, which contains the predicted weight value for each row of data. The idea is that I will then be able to compare the original `Weight` variable with the `prediction` variable at different points in the `Time` variable.

When I try do do this using `mutate` and `predict` functions, I get an error saying that the number of observations used in the model fit (789) is different from the number of observations in the original data frame (861).

```
> new_df <- dietox %>%
+   mutate(prediction = predict(model1))
Error: Column `prediction` must be length 861 (the number of rows) or one, not 789
```

My questions are: 
 1. How do I extract the data frame for the 789 observations that
    were used in the model fit? 
 2. Why is the number of observations
    used in the model fit different to the total number of observations
    in the original data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 789 observations used in model fitting were the ones which were without `NA`. You had 72 observations as `NA` in `Feed` column

```
sum(is.na(dietox$Feed))
#[1] 72
```

and `789 + 72` gives you complete 861 observations. To get all the predicted values you could do

```
dietox$Prediction <- NA
dietox$Prediction[!is.na(dietox$Feed)] <- predict(model1)

head(dietox)
#    Weight      Feed Time  Pig Evit Cu Litter Prediction
#1 26.50000        NA    1 4601    1  1      1         NA
#2 27.59999  5.200005    2 4601    1  1      1   31.43603
#3 36.50000 17.600000    3 4601    1  1      1   36.76708
#4 40.29999 28.500000    4 4601    1  1      1   41.45324
#5 49.09998 45.200001    5 4601    1  1      1   48.63296
#6 55.39999 56.900002    6 4601    1  1      1   53.66306
```

Also the values which were used in the model are present in `model1$y`.